# Check if table is empty in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, exists

I want to know if there is an better way to check if a table of a given database is empty.

My version:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('emails.db')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM (select 1 from my_table limit 1);")
print(cur.fetchall()[0][0])

con.close()
```

Output:

```
0 # If table `my_table' is empty
1 # If table 'my_table' is not empty
```

Comment: How about `select count(*) from my_table` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo can use:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table);
```

this will return 1 row with 1 column which will be `0` if the table is empty or `1` if it contains any rows.

`EXISTS` will return as soon as it finds the 1st row in the table and it will not scan the whole table.

Comment: According to my tests just now, the query plan for this is more complex than `select count(*) from my_table;` and still contains a table scan.

Comment: @Tomalak the difference is that with EXISTS the table scan stops at the first row.

Comment: Okay, if you say so, I'm inclined to believe it. :) I suppose the difference is marginal for any but the very largest of databases.

Comment: @Tomalak just to give you an idea, for a table of 1M rows (just 2 columns) which I have tested, EXISTS returns in 5-7 ms and count(*) returns in on average 295ms.

Comment: Wow, that's significant. Good to know, I'm definitely going to keep that in mind. Thinking about it, that seems kind of an easy optimization to make for the query parser when it sees `select * from ...`

Comment: I suppose `select 1 from my_table limit 1;` would have the same effect - do you still have your test DB around?

Comment: @Tomalak `select 1 from my_table limit 1;` returns in 6-7ms but as it is it does not return 0 if the table is empty. It has to be combined with count(*) just like the OP's code which also returns in 6-7ms.